# Store large amounts of data per session ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, session, asp.net-mvc-4

My MVC based application, hooks some web services which send back lots of data!
Using the same, I render my views. The web services are slow and out of my control.
So I would like to store this info per session, but I am afraid that, this will bring down my web server to its knees. With few hundred users, the web server will run out of memory.

Is there a way that I can store this session data in a file per session? I am more looking at some out of the box open source solutions.

I welcome, new suggestion as well!

Comment: But why you dont want to use Caching?

Comment: @Maris: This data doesn't change very often, but the views which use this data are rendered many times!

Comment: @Maris: Caching is not an option at the moment, as the data is user specific and Session in my opinion is the right candidate for such data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store pretty much any object in the Session storage, with a few exceptions which are generally related to running on a server farm.  I'm going to ignore those cases here however.

If you're dealing with only a few MB of data, storing it in the Session object (or a Cache, as @Rick suggests) isn't necessarily a major problem.  Once the data has been returned from the web service and parsed into your own internal data structures, simply place the data structure's root object into the Session.  I use this method fairly often to store the results of database queries that take a long time to run, especially when the query criteria are unlikely to change frequently.

For larger data sets you should probably use a database to store the information.  Create tables that match the structure of the data you're returning and tag the data in some way to indicate how old it is and what criteria were used when fetching it.  Update as required, and query the database for records on each client request.

There are plenty of other options, including creating temporary files to store the data using the SessionID to identify them, but I recommend investigating the database option first.

Comment: A DB based solution, is an additional dependency. Which I am not ready to invest into. But, if nothing else works, I may be forced to go this way! :(

Comment: Databases are so commonplace these days that I don't tend to think of them as being a problem.  You could use something like [csharp-sqlite](http://code.google.com/p/csharp-sqlite/) if you don't want to go through setting up an full SQL server database.

Answer (score 1):

Caching is your friend. And since you use MS technology you might want to take a look at [the Cache Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache.aspx)

Comment: Caching will also have the same problem, unless it is not in-memory! Plus, this data is user specific! So, in my opinion, session serves best. But large data is my concern.

Comment: So? Use the user/session as cache key and pick memory / disk as the data store. It is still called caching.

Answer (score 0):

You could just serialize the result collection and save it on files as xml (even process it using linq/XPath directly from XML) , or use any .net native xml database to store and persist data on a file.